# Launching of thread for socket connection and painting information about it in Frames

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, frame

I am trying to wirte java-program.

My Idea:
The main class launches thread for socket connection, also the main class launches Frame with GUI.

```
package dialogsubsystem2;

import InternetConnection.SocketConnectionThread;

/**
 *
 * @author ACER
 */
public class DialogSubsystemLauncher {

    public SocketConnectionThread connectionSocket = new SocketConnectionThread("192.0.0.100", 2002);

    public DialogSubsystemLauncher() {

        /* Create and display the form */

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DialogSubsystemLayoutFrame().setVisible(true);                
            }
        });        

        connectionSocket.start();        
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

       DialogSubsystemLauncher dlgLnch = new DialogSubsystemLauncher();


    }
}
```

The created Frame launches another frames by request from user.

I want to show information about the socket connection (from socket connection thread) on statusbar of all Frames.
But I can't to access the socket connection thread from Frames.
How should I solve this problem? 
How should I launch socket connection thread to have access to it from any Frame?

Comment: maybe have the socket connection thread broadcast information which the frames can then receive.

Comment: All Frames are launched within the one PC but all of them can receive the same information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need that one of the objects has a reference to the other. I would point to the frame having a refence to the thread (since the thread may be blocked at times by I/O).

Just make the constructor of the Frame accept a thread object and pass the one you created(or add a set method to it).

EDIT:

In answer to aclarations in comments.

It is to the other classes (the Frames) that you create that you need to pass the reference.

```
public class DialogSubsystemLayoutFrame extends JFrame {
  // You store the reference here.
  private SocketConnectionThread socketConnection = null;

  public DialogSubsystemLayoutFrame(SocketConnectionThread socket) {
    this.socketConnection = socket;
  }
}
```

From there, you can use `this.socketConnection` anywhere in the class to operate with it.

Comment: I initialized socket connection thread within the class `DialogSubsystemLauncher` in a such way

    public static SocketConnectionThread connectionSocket = new SocketConnectionThread("192.0.0.100", 2002);

Now I have acces to socket connection thread from any Frame. 
Does this method have any limitations?

Comment: It works, but `static` is poor style and should be avoided. What if tomorrow you want to use two connectionthreads, and a different frame informing of each one?

Comment: Sorry, I am novice in java. Can you explain it "Just make the constructor of the Frame accept a thread object and pass the one you created" more detailed. As far as I understood each Frame will have it's own thread. Is it right?

Comment: Ok, I missunderstood a little the question, but in the edit is the answer. Basically, everywhere you need to get some information from the thread, you need to pass its reference.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own class that extends the Frame and init the Socket thread in that class.